# Sailsjs what attribute does findOrCreate use to find if a record exists?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, sails.js, waterline

I'm using sailsjs with mysql, and using it to save data from a shopify webhook when an order is placed. It returns a json object, and one of the properties is a customer object, which I'm saving in a different table related back to the main orders table. I'm using findOrCreate on the customer model so I don't have duplicate customers.

Can waterline use a specific attribute to determine if a record is already present? The customer object (from shopify) has an id, but the docs doesn't make it clear if this is going to be the same for a given customer across different orders. Also, if a customer sets a different payment method, billing address, etc would waterline create a new record for it?

To sum up, I need waterline to use the customer_email property to determine if a record exists or not. Is this possible? Sorry for the rambling; I'm thinking through this as I type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`findOrCreate`](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create) takes 2 parameters and a callback 
You should use first to determine whether record exists using unique identifying keys.

E.g.

```
var findCriteria = { id: 1, customer_email: 'abc@example.com' };
var recordToCreate = { id: 1, customer_email: 'abc@example.com', name: 'ABC' };
Model.findOrCreate(findCriteria, recordToCreate, console.log);
```

> [findOrCreate](http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models/find-or-create)
>
> Checks for the existence of the record in the first parameter. If it
>   can't be found, the record in the second parameter is created. If no
>   parameters are passed, it will return the first record that exists. If
>   no record is provided, it will either find a record with matching
>   criteria or create the record if the object can not be found. Eg.
>   `Model.findOrCreate( findCriteria , recordToCreate , [callback] )`

Comment: Thanks! The docs didn't make that clear; it says 'criteria', and I didn't realize that it was referring to a model attribute.